# Fade in and fade out line between nodes in Forest tree

Tags: forest

I would like to have lines fade in and fade out so I can have a tree view in multiple columns and or pages. Please refer to my example provided below. The long node lines would be so much nicer if they were faded in the middle (i.e. make them fully transparent to not cover the text). If it is possible I will use different colors for the ends in order to distinguish which one leading where.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}
\usepackage[paper=A3,pagesize]{typearea}
%För att göra strukturträd
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=north}
[\phantom, phantom
   [Test sample A (0.00.000), l*=6, name=TSAa
    [\dots
     [\dots
      [\dots, name=TSAb
       [obsolete]]]]]
   [New article, l*=14, name=NewArticle]
   [obsolete, l*=15, name=Obsolete]
   [Released article (1.00.000), name=Released2
     [1.00.001
       [1.00.002
         [\dots
          [1.01.000, name=TSAa1
           [1.02.000, l*=5, name=TSAb1
            [\dots
             [\dots
              [1.04.012, name=ChooseNode
               [2.00.000, edge={black!20, dashed}
                [\dots]]]]]]]]]]]

   [Test sample 2 (0.00.000), l*=9, name=TS2a
    [\dots
     [\dots
      [\dots, name=TS2b
       [obsolete]]]]]
   [New article number (0.00.000), name=NewArticleNumber
        [0.00.001
          [0.00.002
            [\dots
              [0.00.123, name=TS1a1
                [\dots
                 [\dots
                  [0.00.321, name=TS2a1
                    [\dots
                      [\dots
                       [0.01.000, name=TS1b1
                        [0.01.001
                         [0.02.000, name=TS2b1
                          [0.02.001, name=Revert1
                          [\dots
                           [0.02.012, name=TS3a1
                           [0.02.013, l*=5, name=TS3b1
                            [0.03.000, name=Revert2, edge={black!20, dashed}
                             [\dots
                               [Release (1.00.000), name=Released1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
   [Test sample 1 (0.00.000), l*=6, name=TS1a
     [0.00.001
       [0.00.002
         [\dots
          [0.00.234, name=TS1b
           [obsolete]]]]]]
   [Test sample 3 (0.00.000), l*=17, name=TS3a
    [\dots
     [\dots
      [\dots, name=TS3b
       [obsolete]]]]]
]
\draw[-] (TS1a1) to (TS1a);
\draw[-] (TS1b1) to (TS1b);
\draw[-] (TS2a1) to (TS2a);
\draw[-] (TS2b1) to (TS2b);
\draw[-] (TS3a1) to (TS3a);
\draw[-] (TS3b1) to (TS3b);
\draw[-] (Revert1) to[out=east,in=east] (Revert2);
\draw[-] (Released1) to[out=east,in=south] (Released2);
\draw[-] (TSAa1) to (TSAa);
\draw[-] (TSAb1) to (TSAb);
\draw[-, black!20, dashed] (ChooseNode) to (NewArticle);
\draw[-] (NewArticle) to[out=east,in=south] (NewArticleNumber);
\draw[-, black!20, dashed] (ChooseNode) to (Obsolete);
\end{forest}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Sample output:
[image: Forest lines]

Comment: What's the point of putting a group around an environment, which is already a group?

Comment: Doesn't this give you an error when you try to compile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer fixes the two causes of compilation errors in the example posted, minimises the preamble and provides a make-believe solution.

Unless you have an extremely good reason not to do so, take my advice: fake it.

[image: fake solution]

This uses filled nodes on the foreground layer and puts the conflicting paths on the background layer, so that they go behind to white boxes. The result is as if the paths were broken to avoid the boxes.

If you want a faded effect, you could fill the nodes with a transparency shading. However, this would be more trouble, more fragile and more of a headache to maintain. Also, you could not do this for the `edge`s. At least, not without elaborate paraphernalia, which might or might not cooperate with Forest. I would, therefore, avoid this and keep things simple.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow=north, fill=white, edge={double=black, draw=white}}
  [, phantom
     [Test sample A (0.00.000), l*=6, name=TSAa
      [\dots
       [\dots
        [\dots, name=TSAb
         [obsolete]]]]]
     [New article, l*=14, name=NewArticle]
     [obsolete, l*=15, name=Obsolete]
     [Released article (1.00.000), name=Released2
       [1.00.001
         [1.00.002
           [\dots
            [1.01.000, name=TSAa1
             [1.02.000, l*=5, name=TSAb1
              [\dots
               [\dots
                [1.04.012, name=ChooseNode
                 [2.00.000, edge={black!20, dashed}
                  [\dots]]]]]]]]]]]
     [Test sample 2 (0.00.000), l*=9, name=TS2a
      [\dots
       [\dots
        [\dots, name=TS2b
         [obsolete]]]]]
     [New article number (0.00.000), name=NewArticleNumber
          [0.00.001
            [0.00.002
              [\dots
                [0.00.123, name=TS1a1
                  [\dots
                   [\dots
                    [0.00.321, name=TS2a1
                      [\dots
                        [\dots
                         [0.01.000, name=TS1b1
                          [0.01.001
                           [0.02.000, name=TS2b1
                            [0.02.001, name=Revert1
                            [\dots
                             [0.02.012, name=TS3a1
                             [0.02.013, l*=5, name=TS3b1
                              [0.03.000, name=Revert2, edge={black!20, dashed}
                               [\dots
                                 [Release (1.00.000), name=Released1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
     [Test sample 1 (0.00.000), l*=6, name=TS1a
       [0.00.001
         [0.00.002
           [\dots
            [0.00.234, name=TS1b
             [obsolete]]]]]]
     [Test sample 3 (0.00.000), l*=17, name=TS3a
      [\dots
       [\dots
        [\dots, name=TS3b
         [obsolete]]]]]
  ]
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[-] (TS1a1) to (TS1a);
    \draw[-] (TS1b1) to (TS1b);
    \draw[-] (TS2a1) to (TS2a);
    \draw[-] (TS2b1) to (TS2b);
    \draw[-] (TS3a1) to (TS3a);
    \draw[-] (TS3b1) to (TS3b);
    \draw[-] (Revert1) to[out=east,in=east] (Revert2);
    \draw[-] (Released1) to[out=east,in=south] (Released2);
    \draw[-] (TSAa1) to (TSAa);
    \draw[-] (TSAb1) to (TSAb);
    \draw[-, black!20, dashed] (ChooseNode) to (NewArticle);
    \draw[-] (NewArticle) to[out=east,in=south] (NewArticleNumber);
    \draw[-, black!20, dashed] (ChooseNode) to (Obsolete);
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great fix. I will go this way. Accepted.